# Opening Specific Card item in RecycleAdapter from different Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I will make this as specific as possible. I've created a Page Which uses RecyclerAdapter to show card items in grid.And I have set a Default Activity for each card using OnclickListner ,So when you click any card item it will take you to that Default Activity [Like this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2V59.gif).And mine one Look Like this [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgk6X.gif).My question is how can I open a perticular card in recyler Adapter from a different activity.In my app I want that when I press Go button on popup It will it toggle lvl2 or the next card to open the game activity.

**Java file for RecyclerAdapter**

```html
package com.example.apptuzzle;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mcontext;
    private List<InGameContent> mData;


    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mcontext, List<InGameContent> mData){
        this.mcontext = mcontext;
        this.mData = mData;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view;
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext);
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_items1,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
         holder.Title.setText(mData.get(position).getTitle());
         holder.Title.setTag(position);

        holder.cardview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 int  pos = (int) getItemId(position) + 1;
                 Intent intent = new Intent(mcontext,InGame_wrkfunction.class);
                 intent.putExtra("pos", pos);
                 //passing data to the InGame_wrkfunction.class
                 intent.putExtra("Answrr",mData.get(position).getAnswrr());
                 intent.putExtra("Thumbnail",mData.get(position).getThumbnail());
                 intent.putExtra("Description",mData.get(position).getDescription());
                 // start the activity
                 mcontext.startActivity(intent);
             }

         });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }




  public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView Title;
        CardView cardview;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.LvL_id1);
            cardview = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_id);


        }

    }
}
```

**Default Game Activity**

```html
package com.example.apptuzzle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class InGame_wrkfunction extends AppCompatActivity  {
    private Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9, btn0, btndot;                //Buttons Declaration
    private Button btnclr, btnsubm, popup_g_button1;
    private TextView txtv1, txtv2, popup_g_msg1, popup_g_des1,highscore1;
    int scores = 0;


    private LinearLayout Popup_layout11;
    private Animation pop_animation;


    private ImageView img,popup_g_img1,popup_b_img;                                                      //Question Declaration
    private TextView txt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_in_game_wrkfunction);


        btn0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btn0);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btn1);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btn2);
        btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btn3);
        btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btn4);
        btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btn5);
        btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btn6);
        btn7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btn7);
        btn8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btn8);
        btn9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btn9);
        btndot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btndot);
        btnclr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnClr);
        btnsubm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnSubm);
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gamethumbnail);
        txtv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TxtV1);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TxtV2);
        Popup_layout11 = findViewById(R.id.Popup_layout11);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TxtV2);
        popup_g_button1 = findViewById(R.id.Popup_G_button1);
        popup_g_msg1 = findViewById(R.id.Popup_G_msg1);
        popup_g_des1 = findViewById(R.id.Popup_G_des1);
        popup_g_img1 = findViewById(R.id.Popup_G_Img12);
        highscore1 = findViewById(R.id.ScoreCounter1);



        pop_animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.pop_up);

        btn0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.input_bttn_colorc);
                txtv1.setText(txtv1.getText() + "0");
            }
        });
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.input_bttn_colorc);
                txtv1.setText(txtv1.getText() + "1");
            }
        });
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.input_bttn_colorc);
                txtv1.setText(txtv1.getText() + "2");
            }
        });
        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.input_bttn_colorc);
                txtv1.setText(txtv1.getText() + "3");
            }
        });
        btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.input_bttn_colorc);
                txtv1.setText(txtv1.getText() + "4");
            }
        });
        btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.input_bttn_colorc);
                txtv1.setText(txtv1.getText() + "5");
            }
        });
        btn6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.input_bttn_colorc);
                txtv1.setText(txtv1.getText() + "6");
            }
        });
        btn7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.input_bttn_colorc);
                txtv1.setText(txtv1.getText() + "7");
            }
        });
        btn8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.input_bttn_colorc);
                txtv1.setText(txtv1.getText() + "8");
            }
        });
        btn9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.input_bttn_colorc);
                txtv1.setText(txtv1.getText() + "9");
            }
        });
        btndot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.input_bttn_colorc);
                txtv1.setText(txtv1.getText() + ".");
            }
        });
        btnclr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtv1.setBackground(null);
                txtv1.setText(null);
            }
        });


        // Receive data

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String Description = intent.getExtras().getString("Description");               //It ll fetch data from Description()
        int image = intent.getExtras().getInt("Thumbnail");
        int pos = intent.getExtras().getInt("pos");
        final String answrr1 = intent.getExtras().getString("Answrr");

        //Setting Values
        img.setImageResource(image);                                                         ////It ll replace the image that was fetched previously
        txt.setText(Description);

        //Load Scores
        SharedPreferences myscores = this.getSharedPreferences("MyAwesomeScores", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        scores = myscores.getInt("scores", 0);  //0 tha phehele
        highscore1.setText("Scores:" + scores);


        btnsubm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String a = txtv1.getText().toString();
                if (a.equals(answrr1)) {
                    scores += 30;
                    //Save scores
                    SharedPreferences myscores = getSharedPreferences("MyAwesomeScores", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myscores.edit();
                    editor.putInt("scores", scores);
                    editor.commit();
                    v.setOnClickListener(null);//Remove setOnClickListener

                    highscore1.setText("Scores:" + scores);


                    Popup_layout11.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
                    Popup_layout11.setAnimation(pop_animation);
                    Popup_layout11.animate();
                    pop_animation.start();
                } else {
                    scores -= 30;

                    //Save scores
                    SharedPreferences myscores = getSharedPreferences("MyAwesomeScores", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myscores.edit();
                    editor.putInt("scores", scores);
                    editor.commit();
                    v.setOnClickListener(null);//Remove setOnClickListener

                    highscore1.setText("Scores:" + scores);


                    popup_g_img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.sadface11);
                    popup_g_msg1.setText("Ohh Snap!");
                    popup_g_des1.setText("Don't worry Kid you just tap the button to move on to the next lesson. REMEMBER 'never waste time'.");
                    Popup_layout11.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
                    Popup_layout11.setAnimation(pop_animation);
                    Popup_layout11.animate();
                    pop_animation.start();
                }
            }
        });

    }

}





/*Two Ways of Putting One Animation In an activity
* 1st One
*        Anim1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.new_animfile1);

      //  pop_img1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                <-----In this type you can put animation inside On Click Listener
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Layout1.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
                Anim1.setDuration(500);
                Layout1.setAnimation(Anim1);
                Layout1.animate();
                Anim1.start();

            }
        });
*
*
*  2nd One
* public class MyActivity extends Activity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);                                            <-----In this type you can set another class outside the OnCreate Bundle
 }

public void animate(View view){
    LinearLayout dialog   = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.dialog);
    dialog.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
    Animation animation   =    AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim);
    animation.setDuration(500);
    dialog.setAnimation(animation);
    dialog.animate();
    animation.start();
 }

}
* */
```

Comment: Have you tried using sharedPreference?

Comment: how can I do that ? I mean is it possible to open any specific position of card using S.P

Comment: I've passed the position from the adapter to main game but I dont know how to use onclick listener with position {int  pos = (int) getItemId(position) + 1;}<-----look in adapter class in onbindViewholder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understand is you want to open different activities on each card click.If it's correct then,

use `switch` inside your onClick and open your activity on a particular item click

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {          

    final Intent intent;
    switch (getAdapterPostion()){
        case 0:
           intent =  new Intent(context, FirstActivity.class);
           break;

        case 1:
            intent =  new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
            break;
           ...
        default:
           intent =  new Intent(context, DefaultActivity.class);
           break;
     }
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Or Use:-

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {          

    final Intent intent;
    if (getAdapterPosition() == sth){
       intent =  new Intent(context, OneActivity.class);
    } else if (getPosition() == sth2){
       intent =  new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
    } else {
       intent =  new Intent(context, DifferentActivity.class);
    }
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: In which class do I put this code Adapter class or the main game activity class

Comment: on your adapter class Handle it in your ```onClick(View v)```

Comment: But I want to open this card from a different activity

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgk6X.gif Please take a look at this inn this the levels page is using the adapter and every level is connected to a same Activity i.e my main game where when give correct answer it will show you a popup that will take you to the next level i.e level 2

Comment: you want to open different activity on each card item click, which you mentioned Like this image link. Am I right?

Comment: Can you contact me on google meet I will explain you with screen share?

Comment: I want to open a card from Default game activity is it possible?

Comment: open the same activity on each item click and send different flags (use position of the item) on each intent and handle your intent on the same activity and check flag. According to flag set your activity data.

Comment: sorry I am just a biggner I don't have any Idea what you are trying to tell.I have send the position of each Item using put extra but how can I handle Intent

Comment: each intent and handle your intent on the same activity and check flag please tell me how can i perform this?

Comment: okay To join the video meeting, click this link: https://meet.google.com/qko-kkiu-cmu

Comment: it is starting from begning when you click go button

Comment: Sir it is getting data from the begning

Comment: add a new question for it in stackoverFlow

Comment: here is the link ::https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61852651/pass-the-current-itemid-from-recycleradapter-to-different-class

Comment: visit my twitter profile mentioned on StackOverflow profile and ask there